# PowerShell script to Create My Site Host Site Collection

Tags: powershell, mysites, user-profile-service-app

I am trying to create My Site Host Site Collection through PowerShell scripts. I am able to create a new web application, set Self Service Site Creation Enabled property on it, Create a new Permission Policy for creating subsites, Associate this Permission Policy to Everyone user in User Policy for this web application, Create a new Managed Path and also create a new Site Collection, all through PowerShell. Now, in the User Profile Service Application, there is a link to Setup MySites. Here we associate the user profile service application with the my site configuration. I need to be able to achieve these steps also through PowerShell, but not able to. I tried to check the properties / methods on the User Profile Service Application and also its Proxy, but couldn't find anything. Can anyone please provide the scripts for this?

Answer (score -1):

Edit - Adding code here for quick reference as per comments.

```
Add - PSSnapin Microsoft.SharePoint.PowerShell - ErrorAction SilentlyContinue   
$MySiteurl = "https://SPMY.Gowtham.com"   
$ServiceContext = Get - SPServiceContext - site $MySiteHost   
$UserProfileManager = New - Object Microsoft.Office.Server.UserProfiles.UserProfileManager($ServiceContext)# Retrive all user Profiles   
$UserProfiles = $UserProfileManager.GetEnumerator()# Loop through each profile   
foreach($Profile in $UserProfiles)   
{   
    if ($Profile.PersonalSite - eq $Null)    
    {   
        if ($Profile.PersonalSite - eq $Null)    
        {#   
            $UserProfile.CreatePersonalSite()   
            write - host "My Site Profile Created Successfully for :"   
            $Profile["AccountName"] - f Green   
        } else    
        {   
            write - host "Site Already Exists for the User:"   
            $Profile["AccountName"] - f Red   
        }   
    }   
}
```

below are some links which might be useful.

https://code.msdn.microsoft.com/office/Create-a-MySite-for-all-8bc8acc7
https://vigneshsharepointthoughts.com/2015/08/26/powershell-command-to-manually-create-a-users-my-site-in-sharepoint/
http://matthewyarlett.blogspot.com/2014/06/script-creating-sharepoint-user-mysites.html

Comment: Please don’t add just a link as answer to a question. If the link breaks, the answer you provided will not be useful for future visitors. Provide an answer of your own and use the link as [reference](http://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/help/referencing). If needed, you can block quote the content from your link. More information is found in our help center, especially [How do I write a good answer](http://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/help/how-to-answer)

Answer (score -2):

This has been answered here. Please find the link below

https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/263b3de6-100c-4ed7-9ee8-853f875664f5/powershell-script-to-create-my-site-host-site-collection?forum=sharepointadmin